# How to change all permisson of folder in python

Tags: python, winapi, python-2.7

i use python to add all allow or all deny permisson of folder:

```
info=win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION
sd=win32security.GetFileSecurity(str(path),info)
acl=sd.GetSecurityDescriptorDacl()
systemName=socket.gethostname()
accountName=getpass.getuser()
sidUser=win32security.LookupAccountName(str(systemName),str(accountName))

acl.AddAccessAllowedAceEx(win32security.ACL_REVISION_DS,
win32security.OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE|win32security.CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE,
win32file.FILE_ALL_ACCESS, sidUser[0])

#acl.AddAccessDeniedAceEx(win32security.ACL_REVISION_DS,
#win32security.OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE|win32security.CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE,
#win32file.FILE_ALL_ACCESS, sidUser[0])

sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(1, acl, 0)
win32security.SetFileSecurity(str(path), info, sd)
```

but when i check permisson of this folder. Both deny and allow permisson was checked. is there any way to change that, only allow or deny permisson checked. Thanks